# How can I use YUI 3 in Yii?

Tags: yii, yui

How can I use YUI 3 in Yii framework? I searched on the internet and I couldn't find anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can load any javascript library with Yii. You can add it to your layout (most likely `protected/views/layouts/main.php`) like so:

```
<?php Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScriptFile(Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/js/yui/yui-min.js', CClientScript::POS_HEAD); ?>
```

Assuming your YUI library is located at `js/yui/yui-min.js`. This will now load that js file into the head section of every view that uses that layout.

You can then use it as per normal. Keep in mind that jQuery is built into Yii, so you may have compatibility issues between jQuery and YUI. Check out [**this post**](http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries) on the jQuery website for more info.

I would also recommend having a look at the [**Yii CClientScript documentation here**](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CClientScript). The CClientScript class manages JavaScript and CSS stylesheets for views within Yii.